# While consuming web api in angularjs returns 404 error

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

This is my code

```
$http.jsonp("http://admin.mlbmcjhs.com/api/Department?&callback=JSON_CALLBACK").success(function (data, status) {
    $scope.Departments = data;
    alert(data);
}).error(function (data,status) {
    alert(status);
});
```

web api is working fine in browser console 
and returning data

but in angularjs it jumps to error() and returning 404

Comment: May you share code of web api controller?

Comment: sure its normal get api

Comment: public IEnumerable<Department> GetDepartments()
        {
            return db.Departments.AsEnumerable();
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be getting a CORS error. I've tested from Plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/q3DVia?p=info)

```
  var url = "http://admin.mlbmcjhs.com/api/Department?&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
  $http({
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/JSON'
    },
}).success(function(response, status, headers, config, statusText) {
    vm.Departments = data;
    vm.status = status;
    vm.headers = headers();
}).error(function(response, status, headers, config, statusText) {
    vm.status = status;
    vm.headers = headers();
});
```

, and I get a CORS error. You will probably need to enable CORS on your webApi.

Comment: [EnableCors(origins: "http://admin.mlbmcjhs.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class DepartmentController : ApiController
    {
        
        private mlbmcdb db = new mlbmcdb();

        // GET api/Department
        public IEnumerable<Department> GetDepartments()
        {
            return db.Departments.AsEnumerable();
        }

Comment: Please check it again that api sir